# Программное создание картинки?

Tags: android, bitmap

В Android 7 есть Easter egg (пасхалка) - котолов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вряд ли, в ресурсах лежат картинки всех котов, APK весит очень мало, а котов много. Получается они как-то создаются программно, а в ресурсах лежит лишь макет. Или даже макет создаётся программно. Как это вообще возможно?

Comment: Коты элементарно рисуются с помощью Canvas: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: Так же возможно что это `VectorDrawable`, места такая графика занимает очень мало, позволяет совмещать разные элементы (отдельные xml с частями рисунка) в одном итоговом, менять цвета и тд.

Comment: на хабре было про котов - https://habrahabr.ru/post/313788/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не известно как это сделано, но как можно такое организовать.

1. Canvas. 
   Это очевидно. Класс Canvas содержит метод «draw». Чтобы нарисовать что-то, вам нужно четыре основных компонента: битмап для хранения пикселей, холст для размещения вызовов рисования (запись в растровое изображение), примитив рисования (например, Rect, Path, текст, растровое изображение) и краска для описания цвета и стиля. От вас потребуется организация алгоритма, для того чтоб кошечки не повторялись и цвет (например глаз) не заливался. Мистично будет выглядеть. Необходимо учитывать все экраны. Кошечка в такой ситуации, может содержать например хеш и по нему динамически отрисовываться.
2. SVG да это отличный вариант для вектора. Чем-то похоже на логику с канвой, но рисовать проще. Берете вектор, разбиваете на нужные элементы(части кошечки), парсите в bitmap, используете  алгоритм раскраски, склеиваете в кошечку. Этот вариант удобен тем что вам не нужно, что-то трансформировать и скейлить. Просто укажите поддержку Svg в gradle.
3. Sprites. Спрайты. Аналогичная логика с SVG только растр, есть плюсы и минусы. Весить будет больше, но работать будет максимально просто, вырезается очень просто, те парсить ничего не придется. Один раз пробежаться по картинке, чтоб формы собрать. Но нужно учитывать, разные разрешения это минус. После динамический раскрас и склеивание в 1 bitmap, сохраняем параметры цвет, форма и записываем уникальный номер или хеш, по которому можно воспроизвести алгоритм.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь знаю куда копать, попробую написать аналогию с домиками :D

Comment: Я думаю это многим будет интересно, ссылку бы потом в гит.

Comment: Ок, тоже так думаю)

Comment: @Flippy только зачем SVG когда есть нативный VectorDrawable? кроме того, при использовании VD не требуется никакого динамического кода , парсинга в Bitmap и каких то алгоритмов (хотя при желании можно и программно манипулировать результатом конечно же) - все создается статически через xml (создаются xml cat1, cat2 и тд, в которых указывается из каких, заранее заготовленных, "частей" (других xml) состоит изображение, какой цвет и пр.), потом просто указывается имя ресурса, как @drawable/cat1 - но это если нужны похожие иконки в приложении, например

Comment: VectoDrawable это и есть SVG в абстрации AndroidStudio, который создается в разметке xml и не получится у вас динамически перекрашывать path в VectorDrawable. Вам придется нарезать кусочки (формы кошечек) подготовленные и клеить, а заливать динамически всю VD, кстати не всегда это корректно работает.

Comment: там есть тег <group></group>. как я понял, объедененным через него частям можно указать нужный цвет, впрочем тайна создания котиков [полностью раскрыта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735000/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8#comment1118904_735000), это действительно части котов в VectorDrawable, которые собираются и окрашиваются динамически